# how can we get value from dictionary if key is declare as nullable?

Tags: c#

i have a scenario where a property is define as null able int and i have dictionary where the keys and values are loaded.i want to get the value by giving a key which is nullable int type and if key is null or key is not exist in dictionary then dictionary return a default value.

this is an example

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Dictionary<int, string> students = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 111, "a"},
    { 112, "b"},
    { 113, "c"}
};
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int? a;
        a = 111; //this value is coming from somewhere else and it can be null
        string student = students[a];
    }


}
```

if we define int? a; as int a; then it is not giving error.but i have to make "a" variable as null able.
please help me.

Answer (score 4):

### How to Handle Nullable Types:

You need the `Value` property:

```
string student = students[a.Value];
```

> The Value property returns a value if one is assigned. Otherwise, a
>   System.InvalidOperationException is thrown.

Or change your dictionary to have a nullable key:

```
Dictionary<int?, string> students = new Dictionary<int?, string>()
{
     { 111, "a"},
     { 112, "b"},
     { 113, "c"}
};
```

Or if you need to check if the `Nullable` variable *Has a Value*:

```
string student = null;
if (a.HasValue)
    student = students[a.Value];
else
{
    // do something about it
}
```

> The HasValue property returns true if the variable contains a value,
>   or false if it is null.

### To Answer your Main Question:

All the above is to make your code compile with Nullable types, as for checking if a value is present in the dictionary, you can follow this approach using TryGetValue:

```
string student = null;

if(a.HasValue && students.TryGetValue(a.Value, out student))
{
    // key found and Value now stored in student variable
}
else
{
    // key not found, student is null
}
```

Note: The above assumes the dictionary is still defined as `Dictionary<int, string>`. That's the reason we have the `a.HasValue` check.